# Swagger yaml - $ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I got the following YAML, when I try this, in https://editor.swagger.io/ I'm getting "$ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs" error when I use [ and ] brackets, I tried encoding them but the response schema is not getting recognized, saying the reference is missing. Any help on what can be the issue in this scenario?

```
swagger: "2.0"
info: 
  title: test
  version: "1.0"
paths:
  /api/TestCustomer:
    post:
      consumes:
        - application/json
        - text/json
      produces:
        - application/json
        - text/json
      parameters:
        - name: request
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UpdateTestCustomerRequest'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Test Response
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Result[UpdateTestCustomerResponse]'   ***This line results in a error "$ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs"

definitions:
  UpdateTestCustomerRequest:
    type: object
    properties:
      CustomerId:
        type: string
      UpdatedBy:
        type: string
  Result[UpdateTestCustomerResponse]:
    type: object
    properties:
      Status:
        format: int32
        enum:
          - 201
        type: integer
      Response:
        $ref: '#/definitions/UpdateTestCustomerResponse'
  UpdateTestCustomerResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      CustomerId:
        type: string
```

Answer (score 2):

In OpenAPI 2.0, if some schema names contain special characters, they must be URL-encoded in the `$ref` paths. Replace `[` with `%5B` and `]` with `%5D` in the `$ref` path, e.g.:

```yaml
# Incorrect
$ref: '#/definitions/Result[UpdateTestCustomerResponse]'

# Correct
$ref: '#/definitions/Result%5BUpdateTestCustomerResponse%5D'
```

Or better yet, don't use special characters in schema names.

If/when you migrate to OpenAPI 3, you'll have to remove the `[ ]` characters from schema names because the newer versions only allow `A..Z a..z 0..9 _ . -` in schema names.

Comment: Issue is when I do use URL encoding, swagger is unable to recognize UpdateTestCustomerResponse reference(error is missing reference) and swaggerhub cannot generate the response object, any help on that?

Comment: W/r/t "swagger is unable to recognize UpdateTestCustomerResponse reference(error is missing reference)" - I see no errors in the Swagger Editors after fixing the `$ref`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoQcE.jpg Make sure to only change the `$ref` and not the schema name itself.

Comment: W/r/t "swaggerhub cannot generate the response object" - what exactly do you mean by "cannot generate"? Cannot display the response in the API docs panel, or doesn't include this response when generating server/client code, or something else?

Comment: yes, swagger editor looks fine after encoding there are no errors and I'm only updating $ref, but it doesn't display the response in the API docs panel, it says missing reference, might be the $ref is encoded(#/definitions/Result%5BUpdateTestCustomerResponse%5D) but the definition is Result[UpdateTestCustomerResponse]

Comment: I see the response rendered correctly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T9Qh.jpg Try refreshing the page maybe?